# rails not rendering pages in users controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I go to any page, in the `home_controller` for example, I will see:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Aug 03 12:32:32 -0400 2011
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/home (5.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 49ms (Views: 48.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

And the page `HomeController#index` renders/loads perfectly.

**However**, if I go to a page, like `index` in the `user_controller` (`localhost:3000/user`), nothing changes in the console, but in my browser I get a stale view with stale data. I do not understand why this is happening. I've reinstalled ruby, rails and their dependencies. Caching is turned off. Any changes made the to `user_controller` or user views, doesn't make a difference. What I see in the browser is stale. I don't get it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it isn't actually rendering what you think it is?

- Can you still access the user controller pages if your server is turned off?
- Are there perhaps files in the public folder that would override your user-controller views?
- Try restarting your machine? Perhaps some rogue ruby processes are messing with you.

Comment: I can't access the pages when server is off. When I do a revert revision, it pulls the data ONE time and then it goes stale forever (keeps displaying that one data pull endlessly). Restarting didn't help either :/

Comment: It looks like a user.html file was created! Thank you for knocking me in the head! Any idea why this might have happened?

Comment: I would guess it was generated by some kind of caching scheme that didn't get cleaned up, but I don't actually know.